# IllegalStateException while creating nested entities

Tags: spring-data, h2, java-11

I'm having nested hierarchy on entities, 
Survey 
-Question[] 
--Answer[]

And I'm having troubles with persisting it. Before I added `@PrePersist` methods, It worked **almost** fine, child entities had empty foreign key's to parents. I found another similar question, that suggested to use `@PrePersist` to fix that issue, so I tried, but, it causes

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`

JSON that returns from calling this method looks like that
`{"id":1,"title":"Test Survey","description":null,"endingDateTime":null,"questions":[{"id":1,"content":"Test Question","survey":{"id":1,"title":"Test Survey","description":null,"endingDateTime":null,"questions":[{"id":1,"content":"Test Question","survey"`.... and it keeps repeating over and over again.

If thats important in this case, I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.2 and Java 11.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey")
public class Survey implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "survey_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "survey")
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() {
        questions.forEach(q -> {
            q.setSurvey(this);
        });
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Long id;
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")
    private Survey survey;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() {
        answers.forEach(a -> {
            a.setQuestion(this);
        });
    }
}

@Entity
public class Answer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    private Integer votes;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
}

   public Survey createSurvey() {
        Answer answerA = Answer.builder()
                .content("A").build();
        Answer answerB = Answer.builder()
                .content("B").build();
        Question question = Question.builder()
                .content("Test Question")
                .answers(Arrays.asList(answerA, answerB))
                .build();
        Survey survey = Survey.builder()
                .title("Test Survey")
                .questions(Arrays.asList(question))
                .build();
        return surveyRepository.save(survey);
    }
```

Edit#
If that helps, I'm testing this via GET
At the end of stacktrace I'm getting
`Cannot render error page for request [/result] and exception [Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)`

Not sure why is that happening tho...

Edit#
After logging to H2 console, I see survey, question and 2 answers. None of each have relation from child to parent.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was really simple, on all `@OneToMany` I added `@JsonManagedReference`

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "question")
 @JsonManagedReference
 private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
```

And on `@ManyToOne` I addedd `JsonBackReference`

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
 @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")
 @JsonBackReference
 private Survey survey;
```